# asp.net MVC Bootstrap, replacing the .min.css file

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

This should work and I have no clue why it doesn't, literally all I am doing is creating a new ASP.NET MVC Web application in VS15 Community, and then I replace the existing min.css file with another one (from bootswatch). And it doesn't change anything.

I have practiced mvc for a bit and every time I tried to change my layout later on in the project, it worked every time, but now as I just decided to get it out of the way straight up it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you haven't changed bundleConfig.cs at all, it's only going to use *.min.css when not running in debug mode.  You will also need to replace *.css when running locally from VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to change the non-minified version as well.

Edit: Because the minified version is used when you publish and the non-minified version is used during debug, generally.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, i don't know why replacing just the .min worked before